# Needing help structuring a navbar on html and CSS

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm new to HTML and CSS.
I'm trying to make a website, and I'm starting with the navbar, but this navbar is not "scalable" for every screen side, when it is on full screen fine but when I minimize it it does not load the part on the right side which is "About". All of the menus are pointing to the same page and for now that's the objective.

Here's the Code:

```css
body {}

.navbardiv {}

.navbar_ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*overflow:hidden;*/
  background-color: #333;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  margin: -8px;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 600px;
  height: 70px;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 150px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<!--NAVBAR-->
<div class="navbardiv">
  <ul class="navbar_ul">
    <li class="navbar_li_Contact"><a href="index.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="navbar_li_WebHosting"><a href="index.html">Webhosting</a></li>
    <li class="navbar_li_About"><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You're setting min-width to 600px, so when you minimize the screen so that it is less than 600 pixels, it's probably cutting off part of your navbar. Try setting the width to 100% or something similar and see if that works.

Comment: You also have a large amount of padding around the list items which will likely push them onto new lines when being viewed on a small screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the padding for li to `150px` which is very high, you need to reduce.

But if you want the links to take the whole width and to be evenlly spaced, then you can use flex box and `justify-content: space-between;`

**see code snippet:**

```css
body {}

.navbardiv {}

.navbar_ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*overflow:hidden;*/
  background-color: #333;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  margin: -8px;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 600px;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<!--NAVBAR-->
<div class="navbardiv">
  <ul class="navbar_ul">
    <li class="navbar_li_Contact"><a href="index.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="navbar_li_WebHosting"><a href="index.html">Webhosting</a></li>
    <li class="navbar_li_About"><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Also maybe set `min-width` to a smaller level than 600px, because that's going to cause problems on smaller screens as well.

Comment: But if I do it like that when I change to full size It, the "About" won't be on the left right corner and the "WebHosting" won't be on the center and the other one on the top left corner

Comment: @Tijmen I reduced to 316px

Comment: @SamuelFerreira do you want to evenly defuse the links no matter what the screen size is?

Comment: I want to defuse the links no matter the size of the window but one on the top right corner, another on the center and the other on the top left corner

Comment: @SamuelFerreira you need to use flexbox then ... i edited my answer take a look

Answer (score 0):

Your navbar is not responsive because of `min-width: 600px;` part. What this one will do is that when screen resolution is below 600px in width it will keep your navbar at 600 px. Thus it will align it to leftmost part of the screen which will leave you a cropped right edge.`min-width:100%;` wont work either since it will start to crop when inner elements of the navbar will not fit.

It is easy to fix this. Just change it to `width:100%;`.